# Non-primitive to primitive cast in Rust?

Tags: casting, rust, type-conversion

I'm trying to verify an IP address in Rust, but I can't find a solution casting a `str` into a `u8` that doesn't involve using nightly Rust:

```
use std::net::{IpAddr, Ipv4Addr};

fn verify_address(address: String) -> bool {
    let v: Vec<&str> = address.split('.').collect();

    let v_u8: Vec<u8> = v.iter().map(|c| *c.to_owned() as u8).collect();

    let addr = IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(v_u8[0], v_u8[1], v_u8[2], v_u8[3]));
        //.expect("ERR: Error parsing IPv4 address!");

    if !addr.is_ipv4()  {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `str` as `u8`
 --> src/lib.rs:6:42
  |
6 |     let v_u8: Vec<u8> = v.iter().map(|c| *c.to_owned() as u8).collect();
  |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types. Consider using the `From` trait
```

Comment: Why are you try to *cast* a string to an `u8`? Wouldn't you rather have to *parse* it?

Comment: Rust doesn't really have "primitive types", not in the same way Java uses the term. For example, arrays, slices, references, tuples, `str`, and closures are all primitive-ish. The closest thing you get to a Java-like "primitive type vs. reference type" distinction is `Copy` vs. non-`Copy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reread the chapter about [error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch09-00-error-handling.html?highlight=error,handling#error-handling). You do not need all this:

```
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;

fn main() {
    let ip = "127.0.0.1".parse::<Ipv4Addr>();

    match ip {
        Ok(ip) => println!("valid"),
        Err(e) => println!("invalid"),
    }
}
```

---

About your question, you can use primitive cast for... primitive types only. You must use `From` and `Into`, or `parse` if you convert a `&str` into another type.

Comment: This is useful *but doesn't answer the posed question*.

Comment: @Shepmaster *I'm trying to verify an IP address in Rust*: this is the real question.

Comment: Then edit the OP's question to make it what you think it should be, communicate with the OP to clarify the question, etc.

Comment: @Shepmaster I added a line in my answer.